# c# List<> item is being overwritten by the next item

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, list

I have the following code:

```
//for each player, calculate his position rating
for (int i = 0; i < viewModel.PlayerList.Count; i++)
{
    var player = viewModel.PlayerList[i];

    var positionList = new List<Position>();
    for (int j = 0; j < viewModel.PositionsStatic.Count; j++)
    {
        var position = viewModel.PositionsStatic[j];
        var positionPlayerRating = 0;

        for (int k = 0; k < player.AttributesList.Count; k++)
        {
            var attrib = player.AttributesList[k];
            try
            {
                var selectedAttrib = 
                    position.AttribsByPosition.FirstOrDefault(x => x.AttributeId == attrib.AttributeId);
                if (selectedAttrib != null)
                {
                    positionPlayerRating = positionPlayerRating + selectedAttrib.AttributePlayerPosMult * Convert.ToInt32(attrib.AttributeValue);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                string exc = exception.Message;
                throw;
            }
        }

        position.PositionPlayerRating = positionPlayerRating;
        positionList.Add(position);
    }

    player.PositionList = new List<Position>(positionList);

    playerList.Add(player);
}
```

and the problem is that in the playerList, the PositionList is always the same for each and every player.  What is happening is that it is taking the next PositionList and overwriting the previous one, so effectively I have all the players with the last positionList, instead of different positionLists.

I tried every thing I could think of but no luck.

Comment: Please show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem. My guess is that your `playerList` just has multiple references to the same `Player` object, but we can't really tell from what you've shown us.

Comment: Consider using `foreach` instead of `for` when you only need to do something with each item in a collection without the need to know the location in the collection.  That will make your code much more readable.

Comment: On an unrelated note, that `catch` block is useless so the try/catch structure should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

You are executing the same position loop for every player. The position are not being overwrited by the last one but the last one is picked for each of them.

**Review your logic.**

Answer (score 0):

As you're getting each position from your viewmodel, same `position` objects in the list will get pulled every time, for each player.

So, let's say for player A and `viewModel.PositionsStatic[0]` you assign the PositionPlayerRating and adding it to the position list. If the same object i.e. `viewModel.PositionsStatic[0]` is pulled up and modified for the player B, it will override the rating of player A.

Comment: ok I will have to change my logic and pass a new PositionList for every player

Comment: I'd prefer to clone the `position` object, before saving it in `positionList`.

Comment: You create a new object (clone). You can modify the cloned object without any changes being reflected in the original object and vice-versa. See the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable.clone%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).